# Procedure (sub) to choose cell and assign rgb-interior.color

Tags: excel, vba, cell, background-color

I would like to build a flexible sub to define the background color of cells. All five parameters should be defined *outside* the sub on the Excel sheet.
Up to now I only manage to define the Cells-references *inside* the sub to the five cells B2 to F2 on the sheet, containing row and column of the cell to be colorized and the rgb values by the following code:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim isect As Range
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("b2:f2"))
    fieldRow = Cells(2, 2)
    fieldColumn = Cells(2, 3)
    fieldRed = Cells(2, 4)
    fieldGreen = Cells(2, 5)
    fieldBlue = Cells(2, 6)
    Debug.Print "row: " & fieldRow & ", column: " & fieldColumn & ", Red: " & fieldRed & ", Green: " & fieldGreen & ", Blue: " & fieldBlue
    Cells(fieldRow, fieldColumn).Interior.Color = RGB(fieldRed, fieldGreen, fieldBlue)
End Sub
```

If another column is added before column A, all cells params need to be changed
and if another field is to be colorized, the sub code needs edited too. That is why I would prefer to pass all information by variables to the sub. But I did not find a way to do so. I know that passing variables works but then I do not know how to trigger colorizing.
Thank you very much in advance for any hints!
Florian

here is a screenshot of above example:

[image: figure 1]

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` handler can only take the arguments defined by the `Worksheet.Change` event, so you cannot modify its signature. If the worksheet structure isn't set in stone consider using _named ranges_ to get the cells that contain the values you need - something like `fieldGreen = Me.Range("FieldGreenColumn").Cells(2).Value`, where `FieldGreenColumn` refers to the appropriate worksheet column; if columns are inserted, the referring address will just shift over.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu,
So you recommend to put all five values in a named range which will be available by the sub as shown in your example. I will give it a try

Comment: Maybe try to make a named range of your parameter on the sheet. For example, name it as "param" with the range b2:f2. With a named range, when you add a column before col A, the range reference will be automatically shifted by Excel (so it's no longer b2:f2) if you see in Name-Manager. Then try to have something like this : `if not  application.intersect(target, Range("param")) is nothing then` ... next line `with range("param")` .... next line  `rw= .Cells(1, 1):clmn= .Cells(1, 2):R = .Cells(1, 3):G= .Cells(1, 4):B= .Cells(1, 5)` ... `end with`, then your formatting code line, then `end if`

Comment: If you want to define it in the sub, then I think you need to click a button and the code will ask the user with 5 times input box, where the user fill the rw, clmn, R, G and B in each input box.

Comment: Thanks for all your hints! The code is implements now, currently not as named range but with offset params for added rows or columns